# How to change the link in search results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

We have a request to change the search results to link to an external site. When searching currently, it shows the correct List Items in the results. When clicking a list item, it takes the user to the DispForm.aspx page. However, we would like it to link to an external site which is another column (hyperlink) in that list item.

I've played with Search settings, but can only change the scope of the results. Is there a way to change the link of the list item in the results?

[image: search results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the options could be "Microsoft answers" - e.g. bookmarks, Q&As.
[Manage bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/manage-bookmarks)

The other Option - update results layouts (it's a new feature - check MC489165)
[Manage result layouts for SharePoint results in Microsoft Search](https://vladilen.com/software/microsoft-365/manage-result-layouts-for-sharepoint-results-in-microsoft-search/)

Answer (score 1):

To configure a custom results page in SharePoint Online follow the steps below:

1.Browse to the site where you would like to configure a custom results page and go to Site Settings > Site Collection Settings > Search Settings.

2.In Search Settings, clear selection from Use the same results page settings as my parent, choose Send queries to a custom results page, and provide a value for Results page URL:. Then, save your changes. The URL you use here should be for the page that you created to use as your custom results page.
More information please refer to:
[Create a custom search results page in SharePoint Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/create-search-results-pages)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you'll need to modify adaptive card designer layout listed under Search & Intelligence>Admin Center for that specific search result/Result Types under Customizations.  Modify "TextBlock" type and its text (url).